# Vue.js vue-router from object won't update in navigation guard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, navigation, vue-router

Basically my issue is that when using navigation guards like `beforeEach` or `beforeRouteEnter` the `from` parameter is `{name: null, meta: {…}, path: "/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}`, this is a problem when I'm trying to redirect to a route since once there, `from` is still null.

So, I have this routes definition:

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: '/dashboard',
      name: 'Dashboard',
      component: Dashboard,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'profile',
          name: 'Profile',
          component: Profile
        },
        {
          path: 'config',
          name: 'Config',
          component: Config
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

My before guard looks something like this, both on main.js or on Dashboard.vue (it only changes the guard name):

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log(to)
  console.log(from)
  if (from.name !== 'Profile') {
    next({ name: 'Profile' })
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

This outputs a loop of `to` and `from` that looks like this:

```
{name: "Dashboard", meta: {…}, path: "/dashboard/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
{name: null, meta: {…}, path: "/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
{name: "Profile", meta: {…}, path: "/dashboard/profile", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
{name: null, meta: {…}, path: "/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
{name: "Profile", meta: {…}, path: "/dashboard/profile", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
{name: null, meta: {…}, path: "/", hash: "", query: {…}, …}
```

it keeps looping on the (null and "Profile") tuple, `from` never changes to "Profile".

It doesn't really seems to me like it should behave this way because I expect it to redirect before trying the guard again, not sure either if it's a bug or an expected behavior.

To reproduce the bug I used `vue init webpack project` and then updated as wrote above.

Comment: you probably should not have duplicate route names

Comment: Hi @samayo not sure about which of the routes described above are being duplicated, can you please explain it to me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't edit your Question to include the Solution. Instead, [post your own self-answer and mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or mark the answer that solved it as accepted.